# Message : TestFixtureSetup failed in Service test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I have written Nunit tests for my Services.Things are working properly in almost all the cases except two of them where i am getting "Message : TestFixtureSetup failed in Service test name" when i am running all tests from the Visual Studio Test Menu whereas when i am debugging or running one by one these two also are getting passed correctly ..

What can be the possible solution .?

Update..

```
    [Test]
    public void Service_Test()
    { 
        var handler = appHost.Container.Resolve<StudentService>();
    }
```

The error from the error console window is pointing to first line of the Code..

Comment: You have to provide some code to answer that question. Anyway just enable stopping the debugger at exceptions. Thus you´l probably get where in your code you get the error that hinders you on instantaiet teh test-

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have updated my post with little code..The error from the error console window is pointing to first line of the Service Test

Comment: @HimBromBeere When i am debugging the code my test is getting passed successfully. While running all the tests at one time fron VS Test Menu these two tests are getting failed

Comment: Do the errors also occur if you run all your codes in debug-mode at once instead of one by one manually?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you so much ..I got the error now.I will resolve ..On debug all , i am getting the error which i will resolve ..Thanks a lot !!